# Showing $(f'_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the sequence of derivatives $(f_n')$ when,

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$$

for $x\in [0,1]$

So I calculated the derivative with respect to x and got the following,

$$f_n'(x) = x^{n-1}$$

So $f_n'(x)$ converges pointwise to 0 if x is in $[0,1)$ and $1$ if $x=1$

I believe I have done this part correct and now I am trying to prove whether or not it has uniform convergence.

To do so I want to use the fact that

$$sup|f'n(x)-f'(x)| <= b_n$$

where $limb_n = 0$ then it would be uniformly convergent.

so for $x=1$

$$sup|f'n(x)-f'(x)|$$
$$=sup|x^{n-1}-1|$$

and for $x\in [0,1)$

$$sup|f'n(x)-f'(x)|$$
$$=sup|x^{n-1}|$$

How do I proceed from here and determine if it is uniformly convergent or not?

Comment: Do you mean $|f'_n(x)-f(x)|$? One is differentiated while the other is not differentiated?

Comment: yes sorry I will edit that in

Comment: would you be able to help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

A uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions has a continuous limit, which is not the case here, so we know the sequence does not converge uniformly.

To show this, it would suffice to show that, for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$, there exists $x\in (0,1)$ such that $f_n(x)=x^{n-1} > 1/2$ (since this would mean that, for $\varepsilon=1/2$, and for all $n$, there exists $x$ such that $\vert f_n(x) - f(x)\vert = x^{n-1} > \varepsilon$). Indeed, since $f_n(0) = 0, f_n(1) = 1$, there exists $x\in (0,1)$ such that $f_n(x) = 3/4$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: is there a way to show this using the argument I stated above?

Comment: Based on my answer, we have $b_n \geq 3/4$ for all $n$, and so the series isn't uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give a theorem which may give you a hint, I will also prove the theorem.

Theorem: if $f_n$ uniformly converge to $f$ on $[a,b]$ and each is continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

Proof. Let $I=[a,b]$ Let $x_0 \in I$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let N be so that for every $n > N$ and $x \in I$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Fix $n >N$.

The function $f_n$ is continuous. So, there is $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \delta$, Thus,

$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)| < 3\epsilon$

QED.

We conclude that $x^{n-1}$ does not uniformly converge on $[0,1]$